# Placing a web application in a web page without using an iFrame?

Tags: web-applications, iframe

I have a website and I need to place a web application inside one of its pages. The web application obviously has many pages and they are of varying heights. I was thinking of placing it inside an iFrame. However, with an iFrame, I have the auto height problem. Since the links change within the iFrame itself, it is more difficult to adjust its height, since only the contents inside the iFrame itself will be changing and not the actual page itself (i.e. the URL).

Is there a more clever and cleaner way how I can implement this without using an iFrame.

I also tried using ssi includes but for some reason, they are working everywhere else but when I place the application inside an include, it won't work.

Many thanks

Comment: Would a scroll bar inside the iframe be acceptable? Apart from an iframe you could consider inserting HTML into the DOM. Do both the webpage and the webapp come from the same domain?

Comment: I tried inserting HTML into the DOM using includes but it won't work for some reason. The thing is, I didn't designed the web site and it is using jQuery to allow content sliding and I think that this is the reason why includes are not working. Yes they both come from the same domain, and no scrolling is not acceptable, that would be too easy :)

Comment: any reason you can't do: parent.document.getElementById('the-iframe-id').height = document['body'].offsetHeight;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the onLoad of the iframe:

```
parent.document.getElementById('the-iframe-id').height = document['body'].offsetHeight;
```

Comment: This works on all browsers! thanks! However, the outer design is poorly impemented and there are various elements which also need to change their height in order for the iframe height to occur. This may be because it has jQuery functionality to scroll between frames... Now, I either fix this design, or I change all elements height on page load, not only the iframe height. Anyway, thanks!